# Why can't I get the index of a filtered realm List?

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to find the index of an item in a List<> object after the item has been appended to it, so that I can insert into a tableview.

The tableview is sectioned with `.filter`s so I have to apply the filter before looking for the indexPath. However, the filter appears to break the `indexOf` functionality.

I noticed that the function `.map` has the same effect.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Model: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    let items = List<Model>()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var models: Results<Model>?
    var parentModel: Model?
    var items = List<Model>()
    let realm = try! Realm()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "IsNotFirstTime") {
            populateRealm()
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "IsNotFirstTime")
        }

        models = realm.objects(Model.self)

        parentModel = models!.first
        items = parentModel!.items

        let child = Model()
        child.title = "Child"

        try! realm.write {
            parentModel!.items.append(child)
        }

        print(items.index(of: child)) // prints correct value
        print(items.filter({ $0.title == "Child" }).index(of: child)) // prints nil
    }

    func populateRealm() {
        let parent = Model()
        parent.title = "Parent"
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(parent)
        }
    }
}
```

The first print finds the object, but the second print doesn't, despite the mapping having no overall effect.

The strange thing is that the object IS in the filtered list, doing:

```
print(items.filter({ $0.title == "Child" }).first
```

Returns the object, so it is there.

### Edit

On further inspection, it looks like it's not the filter but the conversion of array type that breaks the functionality, converting to array without a filter does the same thing.

```
print(Array(items).index(of: child)) // prints nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. The filter syntax I used `.filter({ $0.title == "Child" })` isn't the Realm filter, and converts the List to a `LazyFilterCollection<List<Model>>`, which doesn't seem to be compatible with searching for the index of a realm object.

The fix was to use the format `.filter("title == %@", "Child")`, which returns a realm Results object.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use [mapping](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2908681-map) you should add an attributes to map your objects according to it for example

```
    print(items.map({ $0.id }).index(of: child.id))
```

if you use it on this way it will return what you expected

Comment: In my example I used `.map` but in my actual code i'm using `.filter`, I just used `.map` as it was easier to demonstrate my point - but it has the same effect

Comment: So you want to use `.filter` instead of using `.map` ? and when you use `filter` you got nil ?

Comment: Yep - exactly that

Comment: Updated the question to reflect that